# $f/\gcd(f,f')$ is separable

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

> If $f\in F[x]$ is a nonzero polynomial, then $f/\gcd(f,f')$ is separable.

I think it's hard and somewhat dirty to prove this by only polynomial argument. Is there any better way to prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "only polynomial argument"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to considering a finite extension of the field, you can assume that $f$ and $f’$ split in $F$.

Thus, let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$ of multiplicity $\mu \geq 1$. Then $(X-\alpha)^{\mu-1}|f’$, so the multiplicity of $\alpha$ as a root of $f/\gcd(f,f’)$ is at most $1$. So $f/\gcd(f,f’)$ is split in $F$ and has only simple roots thus is separable.

Comment: Oh, it's not that hard. Thanks.